# c# mvvm binding button commandparameter to control outside compositeCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm just not getting it: I've a ribbon-menu where some tabs/groups/buttons are defined in xaml and some tabs/groups/buttons are defined during runtime (user loads a certain "command set"). To realise this I put the ribbonTab which is defined in xaml and a collection container inside a compositeCollection.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="test_ribbonButtonBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility    /2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test_ribbonButtonBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="    {StaticResource svm}">
    <RibbonWindow.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="tabs" Source="{Binding ribbon}"/>
    </RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon x:Name="RibbonMenu" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Ribbon.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <RibbonTab Header="Testtab" >
                        <RibbonGroup x:Name="Testgroup" Header="Testgroup">
                            <RibbonButton LargeImageSource="Icons/question.png" Label="TestAddCommand" Command="{Binding cmdTestAddCommand}" />
                            <RibbonButton LargeImageSource="Icons/question.png" Label="TestReadCommand" Command="{Binding     cmdTestReadCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,     ElementName=lstSequence}"/>
                        </RibbonGroup>
                    </RibbonTab>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource tabs}}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </Ribbon.ItemsSource>
        </Ribbon>
        <ListView x:Name="lstSequence" ItemsSource="{Binding sequence}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" SelectionMode="Extended"/>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Problem now arises for the CommandParameter of the already defined buttons:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=lstSequence'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem=null; target element is 'RibbonButton' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')
```

This might be simple but I just can't wrap my head around it: how do I bind the commandparameter to the selectedItems in the ListView. It's obviously the wrong dataContext.

What further confuses me: if I leave out the composite collection (so all tabs are just defined inside the xaml) the command binds correctly to the element inside the viewmodel and the commandparameter binds correctly to the elements in the window (how does this work anyway, should BOTH bind to the viewmodel as it is specified in the DataContext of the window???)

Any help appreciated.

Resu

EDIT:

Finally setting a setter property in the listview solved the problem

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But I'm still wondering why my method doesn't work anypody else an explanaition for this?

Comment: You can easily overcome this issue by binding `SelectedItem` of `lstSequence` to something in view model. Then you don't need `CommandParameter`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting it: what do you mean with "something"? Any idea why "my way" doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, because I will never use `Ribbon` in my software. Perhaps it's another visual tree problem, that ribbon button is outside of it, so it can't access anything directly by name. Then perhaps `RelativeSource` will do, but I'd just bind `SelectedItem` (make `SelectedItem` property in view model, bind `ListView.SelectedItem` to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options (untested):

1) use parent element to *pass* value via `RelativeSource`:

```
<Grid Tag={Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstSequence}>
    ...
        <!-- hopefully there are no other grids on the way -->
        <RibbonButton CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativewSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"
                      Command="{Binding cmdTestReadCommand}" .../>
    ...
    <ListView x:Name="lstSequence" ... />
</Grid>
```

2) do not use parameter at all

```
<ListView SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem, Mode=OneWayToSource} ... />
```

view model:

```
public whatevertype SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

inside command execute delegate

```
var parameter = SelectedItem;
```